# Guardar cada dato de una consulta select en un key de array

Tags: php, mysql, array, select

Se que parece muy sencillo, pero no se bien como hacerlo. Lo único que quiero es imprimir todos los datos que arroje un select en orden para que apracezca los que tienen mayor id primeros. He probado varias cosas y nada. Ahora estoy intentando introducir todos los resultados que da el select en un array ordenados y luego cuando imprima el publicacion[0] sea el que mayor id tenga, y que cuado imprima publicacion[1] sea el siguiente. Pero al hacerlo me da el siguiente error:

```
Undefined array key 1 in
```

Lo que quiero es que cada dato se guarde en una key, cosa que creo qeu no pasa. Agradezco cualquier ayuda o consejo, otra forma de hacerlo... Gracias.
Este es el codigo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $publicacion = array();
  $publicacion[] = $row['publicacion'];
}
echo $publicacion[0];
echo $publicacion[1];
echo $publicacion[2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

- Defines el array dentro del bucle `while`
- Asignas una key (`publicacion`), pero luego usas otra (numérica).

El `ORDER BY id DESC` ya te los debería traer ordenados, así que esto bastaría:

```
# Escribe siempre SELECT específicos
# con las columnas que necesites únicamente
$sql = "SELECT publicacion FROM publicaciones ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    #Si necesitas mostrar el dato in situ
    #no te líes guardando arrays
    echo $row['publicacion'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

O, si necesitas llenar un array para usarlo en otra parte:

```
# Escribe siempre SELECT específicos
# con las columnas que necesites únicamente
$sql = "SELECT publicacion FROM publicaciones ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
# Defines el array fuera del bucle
$publicacion = array(); 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $publicacion[] = $row['publicacion'];
}

# Donde lo vayas a usar, asumiendo que será en otra parte
foreach($publicacion as $item) {
    echo $item['publicacion'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta la publico por si a alguien le es util. El problema estaba en que como el array se creaba dentro del while, solo se almacenaba el primer valor en el key1. Para solucionarlo basta con sacar cunado creas el arrray del while.
Quedaría tal que así:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY Numero DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$publicacion = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $publicacion[] = $row['publicacion'];
}
echo $publicacion[0];
echo $publicacion[1];
echo $publicacion[3];
```